# Get interation number in UMAT

Tags: abaqus

Although it is easy to get the current step or increment number (variables KSTEP and KINC), I can't find an easy way to know the iteration number when inside the subroutine UMAT.

I know the following "if clause" will tell me if I'm in the first iteration of the first increment of the first step:

`IF((KINC.EQ.1).AND.(SUM(STRAN+DSTRAN).EQ.0.0D0)) THEN`

And I also know that I can get the iteration number writing to external files. However, is it possible to do it just inside the UMAT subroutine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is never really a reason to need to know the iteration number in a UMAT. If you think you need to know it, this is often a sign that you there is a better way to achieve what you want to know.

You can use a common block to track how often you enter a umat, and also which iteration you are on. But I really recommend against this. There is no good reason to know the iteration number. Unless your algorithm is perfect it will cause you more problems than it's worth.

Also in your code to check for the first increment - that will not tell you when you are in a real iteration, it will happen in PRE most likely.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm using UMAT to create other .inp files and call these jobs, as a multi-scale solver. So it would be useful (but not strictly necessary) to have the iteration number to name my (thousands of) auxiliary files. But one thing I really need is to know if i'm still in the same increment (i.e. not in the first iteration), and having the iteration number would certainly help me.

Comment: The only way to do it is to save the current incrent number in a common block. Then compare kinc to this saved value. If its the first time they wouldnt match, but for subsequent iterations they would. I stand by my original point though, you shouldn't really be passing information in or out of a UMAT. There are other better subroutines for this.

Comment: May I ask you what do you mean with "There are other better subroutines for this"?

Comment: Generally accessing external files is best done in UEXTERNALDB. Note that this subroutine comes before and after an increment (i.e twice betweeen each increment). This allows you to do an increment in abaqus, export some data, work on the data externally. then before the next incrment starts we go back through UEXTERNALDB and import our modified data. Then the next increment happens in Abaqus.

Comment: If you must do the common block thing, you need to put an *array* in common dimenson equal to the number of integration points (nel*nip) and within `umat` take care to address an array element unique to each integration point.  Ive done such for debugging purposes, but if your algorithm depends on it fundamentally there is something wrong.